# Recovering Ubuntu with Lubuntu Live CD

Tags: 10.04, permissions, lubuntu, data-recovery

My younger sister's computer suffered some major problems recently.  The BIOS corrupted and attempted to load Ubuntu 10.04 in a way it shouldn't have.  I'm not sure of the exact details, but the computer wouldn't start.  Anyway, I put the drive in a new computer and attempted to recover it with a Lubuntu live CD.  When I access her root folder on the mounted drive, it tells me I can't.  What do I do?  I'm not that experienced with Linux.

Here is the error message we get :

`Error opening directory '/media/lubuntu/string-of-numbers/home/user' Permission denied.`

Comment: What's the specific error message?

Comment: `Error opening directory '/media/lubuntu/string-of-numbers/home/user' Permission denied.`

Answer (score 0):

She encrypted her home folder? Try opening a file manager as root (you can do so by running `sudo pcmanfm` in the terminal), and try to access the folder.